# render :action raises ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers, `foo` and `bar`.

`bar#dobar` has a corresponding `dobar.js.erb` file, which renders correctly when directly called with the accept header of

```
*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
```

`foo#dofoo` finishes with the command `render :action => '/bar/dobar'`.  This results in the following error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template foo/bar/action, /application/bar/action with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text,
 :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. 
Searched in:
  * "/Developer/Workspace/MyProj/app/views"
  * "/Users/bdares/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.0/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/foo_controller.rb:16:in `dofoo'
```

I've also tried:

- `render :action => '/bar/dobar', :format => [:js]`
- `render :action => 'bar/dobar'`
- `render :template => '/bar/dobar', :format => [:js]`

What's wrong?

Comment: If you just want to use template then don't call render :action instead call render :template directly. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are just calling template not action,

```
render :template => 'bar/dobar', :format => [:js]
```

Comment: According to the documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render this should work, and there really is little difference.  I get a similar "missing template" message when I use `render :template` as well.

Comment: Your error should be different I mean "missing template <some path>" can you expand the error message you got after change into template?